# Get text from multiple classes in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to crawl data from a website. I use this code

```
import scrapy 

class KamusSetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "kamusset_spider"
    start_urls = ['http://kbbi.web.id/abadi']

    def parse(self, response):
        SET_SELECTOR = '.tur highlight'
        for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):
            yield {
                'name': brickset.css(SET_SELECTOR).extract_first(),
            }
```

and this is the inspect element:

[image]

I want to get every text in the red oval, like mengabadi, mengabadikan, etc. There are multiple class in the 'b' tag => tur highlight. But, I have not get any result.[image]

What's the problem? How to solve it?
I have change my code become this:

```
def parse(self, response):
        for kamusset in response.css("div#d1"):
            text = kamusset.css("div.sub_17 b.tur.highlight::text").extract()
            print(dict(text=text))
```

but still not working. It return null.

Comment: The selector should be `'.tur.highlight'`...

Answer (score 4):

Selector `.tur highlight` means - select elements `highlight` inside all elements with class `tur`.

To select elements with multiple classes use selector without whitespaces :

```
SET_SELECTOR = '.tur.highlight'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it still not working. I can't get text mengabadi, mengabaikan, etc. Why??

Comment: Think the data is rendered through JS. You can use scrapy splash to view the rendered HTML.

Answer (score 2):

As far I understood your question, you want to extract text from the different place (tags) with different class names in single css_selector.

```
text = kamusset.css("div.sub_17::text, b.tur.highlight::text").extract()
```

This will work, surely

Answer (score 0):

This will do!!

```
text : Selector(text=response.body).xpath('//b[@class="tur highlight"]/text()').extract()
```

Will return list with all occurrences.